# Restrict Access To SharePoint Online From Within Organsiation

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have been asked the question "How do we only allow access to our SharePoint Online Tenancy for users within our organisation?"

I understand that defeats the purpose of external sharing but is there a way?

IP address range?

Comment: I believe you can only do that with ADFS and logon restrictions. Really defeats the purpose of a cloud hosted solution, that would kill people from being able to log in from home to check email, onedrive, or any of the other O365 workloads.

Comment: @EricAlexander I agree but I still have to answer the question & try to improve confidence in those people who don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Logon restrictions as part of ADFS can do this, if you weren't planning on using ADFS, then it'll be an added cost to your deployment that you might not have accounted for.

[Limiting Access to Office 365 Services Based on the Location of the Client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh526961%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

If you are using a third party SSO provider, they may have logon restriction options, so it would be good to check with them.

This isn't really a good thing in my opinion. The freedom of being able to work from home without your work PC/laptop is amazing when all your team data, personal data, and email is in O365. It really transforms the way you work.

It looks like there are some additional log in restrictions on the horizon that wouldn't require ADFS, http://ow.ly/CWD8304GyTl.

Comment: The not obvious part of their question is that they want to restrict the employees who have access from downloading content offline. But they still want them to be able to read that content thus being able to copy it. IRM?

Comment: Yes, IRM will allow you to restrict downloading documents.  You can require them to sign in when opening the document, or you can make it so they must download a new copy every so often.  It should be able to restrict downloads outright as well.  I tried tinkering with it in the tenant we have at my work, but our network is blocking some connection to the RMS server, so be wary of that.

Comment: Updated answer, some new controls coming, http://ow.ly/CWD8304GyTl